# Extend Phrequent search engine for projects

Tags: php, phabricator

I'm extending Phabricators Phrequent (Time Tracking) to fit our needs. We need the possibility to filter user time entries by projects. I already extended `PhrequentSearchEngine` to filter by time ranges. But projects are bound over the `objectPHID` and thus the relation depends on the specific object schema, for now these are Maniphest Tasks or Differential Revisions AFAIK.

So my question is: How should I customize `PhrequentSearchEngine` to get a filter for projects?

The only approach I currently see is to make some pre queries to get all PHID of tasks and differential which are related to the queried projects and use these PHIDs in the real query for the user time. But with every new supported user time object I have to extend these pre queries.

Comment: This isn't currently supported and can't be queried efficiently; there's no best approach. If you want to file a feature request against the upstream (see https://secure.phabricator.com/maniphest/) we can discuss supporting this feature, but Phrequent is beta and generally not a priority at this time.